# Retrieve images from sdcard of Android emulator in Ionic Framework

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I run my app in Ionic Framework using `ionic run android`.

What I need is to retrieve all the images in the sdcard of emulator and display it in my view.

I tried using `camera.getPicture()`, but in that function, a list of images in sdcard will be displayed first and from that list, I have to select the images that I need.

But what my requirement is that, I want all the photos from the sdcard to be displayed directly in my view. Is there any function to make it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this by using ionic framework only. [Cordova](http://cordova.apache.org/) is used to do this action which you need. [following link may be helpful for you](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileUploadOptions). :)